# Mongoose mongodb - get all the data from the collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB with Mongoose,
I want to create an list of countries, each country has a name and a list of cities, and each city has a name and a list of hostels.

the users can add new hostels and rate the existing hostels.

my JSON is supposed to look something like this:

```
{[
     countryName: "Argentina",
     cities: [{
        cityName: "Buenos Aires",
        hostels: [{
           hostelName: "hostel A",
           hostelLocation: "Florida Street 180",
           hostelPhone: "+954454646"  
        },{
           hostelName: "hostel B",
           hostelLocation: "28 Mayo Street 180",
           hostelPhone: "+959898944"  
        }]
     },{
        cityName: "Bariloche",
        hostels: [{
           hostelName: "hostel C",
           hostelLocation: "...",
           hostelPhone: "..."  
        },{
           hostelName: "hostel D",
           hostelLocation: "...",
           hostelPhone: "..."  
        }]
     }]
  ],
  [
     countryName: "Brazil",
     cities: [{
        cityName: "Rio De Janero",
        hostels: [{
           hostelName: "hostel A",
           hostelLocation: "...",
           hostelPhone: "..."  
        },{
           hostelName: "hostel B",
           hostelLocation: "...",
           hostelPhone: "..."  
        }]
     },{
        cityName: "Salvador",
        hostels: [{
           hostelName: "hostel C",
           hostelLocation: "...",
           hostelPhone: "..."  
        },{
           hostelName: "hostel D",
           hostelLocation: "...",
           hostelPhone: "..."  
        }]
     }]
  ]
}
```

How do I implement this structure in Mongo?

Comment: Are these the schema definitions? Could you post the model declarations?

Comment: Check out `population` in Mongoose. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: For that you can use something like https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate

Comment: Internally, this will do the same

Comment: You will query on hostels and deep populate them, which in turn will populate the cities and then the countries.

Comment: If you want to query the country, then I suggest keeping the whole of the data in the same collection as subdocuments.

Comment: Yeah, handlind subdocuments can a be a bit of a pain. A nested document structure, however is what MongoDB has in mind when it comes to storing data. You can easily ask the questions related to those here as well.

Comment: What you are talking about is reverse population. There is a plugin for that as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-reverse-populate

Comment: I rewrote my question to make it more clear.

Comment: This JSON structure is how you should store the data in a single collection.

Comment: Please bring back the schema and model declaration as well.

Comment: If I implement this, how will I be able to add new hostels?
this seems like a bad way to store all the data...

the Schema I wrote is wrong so I deleted it.

Comment: In MongoDB, you are encouraged to store data this way. I know it seems wrong, but I'm guessing this is because you must be used to the principles of relational databases where normalisation is enforced.

Comment: You can easily add hostels to the subdocument using the $push operator. Also, Mongoose can help set up IDs for subdocuments as well.

Comment: This is a very useful guide for schema design in MongoDB: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating models?http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Consider using separated cities and having redundant country parameters for a single model method. Also consider using multiple models for not redundant storage.

city name: String,
country: String,
hostels: {hostel info / model reference}

If you want an example app try the one I used.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications